# how to import or connect csv database into php

Tags: php, csv, web, odbc

I'm quite a new developer and I'm currently on a small project of building a web-based data display (charts, table, and stuff) for a large database using PHP.

Our company didn't let us use the SQL to stacking/store more than half a year of data for us, but our auditing division needs data much more past than that.

They gave us a monthly database and it is up to ourselves to combine the data and then share it with the rest of the team.

We are currently using QlikView to merge our files as we don't have any SQL application, (the only thing we can access is myphpadmin which only gives you 2mb limitation to upload).

and sadly....Qlikview only exports into two kinds of database 1. QVD 2.CSV/TXT

I saw a few articles and saw a driver in the ODBC connection management for text in windows, so I thought it was possible to connect the between CSV and PHP.

here is my code i use to generate the header list:

```
<thead>              
<tr>           
        <?php 
               $conn=odbc_connect('splistcsv', '', '');

               $data = "SELECT * FROM splistcsv";

               if($conn){echo "horray";}else{echo"oh no";}

                       $dataquery = odbc_exec($conn, $data);

                       for($i=1; $i <= odbc_num_fields($dataquery); $i++)
                         echo "<th value=".odbc_field_name($dataquery, $i).">".odbc_field_name($dataquery, $i)."</th>"?>
                   </tr>
           </thead>
```

but it keeps returning error:

```
Warning: odbc_exec(): SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC Text Driver] The Microsoft Jet database engine cannot open the file '(unknown)'. It is already opened exclusively by another user, or you need permission to view its data., SQL state S1000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\xampp\htdocs\42project\pagination.php on line 211"
```

but for this line

```
if($conn){echo "horray";}else{echo"oh no";}
```

it returns a proper horray

does anyone have a reference I can use to connect a csv / text database to PHP?
thank you very much before

Comment: try to take a look at this: https://www.cloudways.com/blog/import-export-csv-using-php-and-mysql/

Comment: I already passed my eyes on it, but we have large more than 50 files databases and it seems gonna be taking forever to upload via php connection one by one, if there is anyway to connect it directly, its preferable. but thank you for the reference !